# Heatmap Table with multiple colours. plotly.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap, plotly, d3heatmap

I'm trying to recreate something like this:

[image]

In other words I need to make a heatmap with independent X axis, each one with it's own heatmap colour schema (i.e some the higher the number the greener the background) others the opposite.

I know this is **not** possible with High-Charts. I was wondering if it would be possible with plot.ly. Is it? is there an example I can have a look at?

I've tried adding multiple colorscaleValue as arrays etc but nothing seems to work.

How can I accomplish this? Even with an other library if needed.

```
P.s.
```

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mf5e58tL/2/) as example.

Comment: Can you explain how the chart should work? Do you mean that a seperate column should have independent scale - meaning independent color axis?

Comment: Hi @morganfree yes, the separate columns should have an independent scale & colour axis

Comment: So I guess you need to calculate intermediate colors on your own and set a specific color for each point. In Highcharts you can use some internal helper functions - see poc here http://jsfiddle.net/5jypsz6o/

Comment: Hi @morganfree, thanks for the help. Wouldn't that values "clash" if they are in the same range? (i.e. one column has values between 0 & 10 and the second one between 5 & 15)

Comment: In the second argument in getColoredPoints function you need to specify  stops colors and min/max values of data for 1 column.